# Cannot get css/js files to load using custom router

Tags: php, routes

I've been working (mostly for fun) on a custom router.
It's a work in progress, so any advice is always welcome!

But my main problem is that de css/js files are not loaded anymore.
It looks like the path to the files is attached to the current url, so users/(css path).

In Chrome and Firefox the assets just keep loading, no response/code is returned. If I deliberately cause an exception to be thrown, such as altering the file path, I do see the html of the exception being returned.

I've done a lot of debugging already, and cannot seem to figure it out.

```
    /**
 * @var
 */
private $routes;
/**
 * @var string
 * Todo: add this to an ini file or something
 */
private $base_route = "/index.php";

/**
 * @param $route
 * @param $callback
 * @param string $method
 */
public function addRoute($route, $callback, $method = Route::GET)
{
    $routes = $this->getRoutes();
    if (empty($routes) || !in_array($route, $routes)) {
        $this->setRoute(
            [
                "route" => $route,
                "callback" => $callback
            ], $method
        );
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * @param array $route
 * @param $method
 */
public function setRoute(array $route, $method)
{
    $this->routes[$method][] = $route;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getRoutes()
{
    return $this->routes;
}

/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function handle()
{
    $route = $this->getURI();
    $route = str_replace($this->base_route, "", $route);

    $urlparts = explode("?", $route);
    if (count($urlparts) > 1) {
        $route = $urlparts[0];
        $query = $urlparts[1];
    }

    if ($this->isAssetRoute($route)) {
        $parts = explode("/", $route);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if ($part !== "public") {
                unset($parts[$part]);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        $route = implode($parts);
        return APP_PATH . "/" . $route;
    }

    if (empty($route)) {
        $this->executeCallback("HomeController");
        return;
    }

    $exists = false;
    $routes = $this->getRoutes();
    $requested_method = $this->getMethod();

    if (!isset($routes[$requested_method])) {
        throw new Exception("404: Route {$route} does not exist with method {$requested_method}");
    }

    $declared_routes = $routes[$requested_method];
    $count_routes = count($declared_routes);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_routes; $i++) {
        if ($declared_routes[$i]["route"] === $route) {
            $exists = true;
            $data = $declared_routes[$i];
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (!$exists) {
        throw new \Exception("404: route {$route} does not exist!");
    }

    //Todo: replace [var]
    $route = $this->compileRoute($route);

    $this->executeCallback($data["callback"]);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
private function getProtocol()
{
    return $_SERVER["HTTPS"];
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMethod()
{
    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getURI()
{
    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}

/**
 * @param $route
 * @param $callback
 */
public function get($route, $callback)
{
    $this->setRoute(
        [
            "route" => $route,
            "callback" => $callback
        ], Route::GET
    );
}

/**
 * @param $route
 * @param $callback
 */
public function post($route, $callback)
{
    $this->setRoute(
        [
            "route" => $route,
            "callback" => $callback
        ], Route::POST
    );
}

/**
 * @param $route
 * @return mixed
 */
public function compileRoute(&$route)
{
    $uri = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $formatted_route = "";
    foreach ($uri as $key => $param) {
        $formatted_route .= "/" . preg_replace(
                "/\[(.*)\]/", "1", $param
            );
    }
    return str_replace($this->base_route, "", $formatted_route);
}

/**
 * @param $callback
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function executeCallback($callback)
{
    $callback_data = explode("::", $callback);

    $controller = $callback_data[0];
    if (!isset($callback_data[1])) {
        $method = "index";
    } else {
        $method = $callback_data[1];
    }

    if (!class_exists($controller)) {
        throw new \Exception("Class {$controller} does not exist!");
    }

    if (!method_exists($controller, $method)) {
        throw new \Exception("Method {$method} does not exist!");
    }

    $controller::$method();
}

/**
 * @param $route
 * @return bool
 */
private function isAssetRoute($route)
{
    return (stripos($route, "/public/assets/") !== false);
}
```

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with the `javascript` or `css` tags. If those files would be written in a language nobody knows, your problem would still be strictly limited to php and routing. Think of tags as invitations for people having those skills to come and help. I'm assuming your not calling an electrician to fix your plumbing or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm not talking about CSS or JavaScript tags, I'm talking about files, which can be seen in the sections.
I expect that if I look at the contents, that I see the correct contents of the file, however, I can't see anything.

Comment: How are CSS / JavaScript experts going to help you, assuming they have no knowledge of php? By placing `css` and `javascript` tags on your question, you call for people with proficiency in that technology to come and help. You need `php` proficiency here. That's why I removed the tags. I added the comment so you could understand and tag in your best interest from now on.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood,  I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by getting the correct header for it (`text/css` or `application/javascript` for those wondering), echoing the file contents and then returning;

I put the code for that in the `if ($this->isAssetRoute($route))` statement, located in the handle() method.
All other code in that statement is removed.